# Mocking AWS Cognito Identity pools for frontend unit tests to elevate error: "No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access"

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-cognito

I am working on Frontend Unit Tests (Jasmine, Karma) for an angular project that has utilised a pre-built AWS angular template. I am new to the project and AWS. The app itself works without issue. Ultimately, there should be no AWS/server connection, and all services will be mocked.

The problem I am running into is inconsistent errors arising from seemingly *random* components when the Karma Unit Test spec is run. These components have no AWS related calls or service calls. Many of them are simple and contain mainly front-end templates (**there is no back-end related logic**).

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Cognito Identity pool provided for unauthenticated access

I am still trying to wrap my head around AWS services (User pools, identity pools etc) - and have no idea why this error is occurring.

Could someone please explain what is happening or how I can go about mocking AWS entirely across the app with some sort of configuration, or create a mock user identity pool to elevate this error. I have read what feels like every webpage and am still stuck :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the following issue by *mocking* the Auth service that is called by the application. This could also be completed by adding a spy on the AWS Cognito call. I simply returned fake credentials that would indicate to the app that I was logged in, and told my TestBed module to use that instead of the real AuthService. Below is the only code I added to this mocked service class, and it has worked so far.

**auth.mock-service.ts**

```
AuthContext$ = of({
    username: ''
});
```

This works for my frontend unit tests as there was no need to connect to AWS at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it is happening because the AWS logic is still being ran in a service that is injected into one of the components or those functions still run.

https://testing-angular.com/debugging-tests/#debugging-tests

^ That is a very good resource in learning unit testing but there is the chapter on debugging tests.

https://testing-angular.com/faking-dependencies/#faking-dependencies

^ Here is a chapter on faking dependencies.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935131/7365461

^ Unfortunately, as TypeScript and Jasmine have progressed, it is difficult to mock an npm package like amazon-web-services. I have found the above answer to be the best way.

Hope all of this helps.