# AWS Amplify Cognito Angular Unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing and just decided to add test coverage for my existing app. I am struggling in writing the unit test cases for the given service .
I have created a AWS service file .

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { IUser } from '../../models/userModel';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AwsAmplifyAuthService {
  private authenticationSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.authenticationSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  }

  // SignUp
  public signUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.signUp({
      username: user.name,
      password: user.password,
      attributes: {
        email: user.email,
        name:user.name
      }
    });
   }

  // Confirm Code
  public confirmSignUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.confirmSignUp(user.name, user.code);
  }

  // SignIn
  public signIn(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return Auth.signIn(user.name, user.password)
      .then((r) => {
        console.log('signIn response', r);
        this.authenticationSubject.next(true);
        if (user) {
          if (r.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/forgotpass');
          } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

and created a interface model

```
export interface IUser {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    code: string;
    name: string;
}
```

I have tired the mocking the service in the .spec.

```
    beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Auth,
          useValue: { currentUserInfo: () => Promise.resolve('hello') },
        },
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.inject(AwsAmplifyAuthService);
  });


  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('#signIn should return expected data', async (done: any) => {
    await service.signIn(expectedData).then(data => {
      expect(data).toEqual(expectedData);
      done();
    });
  });
```

I am not able to pass the test case. Any guidance on the same would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is one of the shortcomings of Angular unit testing where it is extremely difficult to mock an import of:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
```

How you have mocked it with the `providers` approach would work if `Auth` was injected in the constructor of the component.

There were ways to mock in the older versions of TypeScript but due to updates, it is difficult to mock imported functions/classes.

What you can do is create a wrapper class for your AWSAmplify like so:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

class AWSAmplifyWrapper {
  static getAuth() {
    return Auth;
  }
}
```

In your service, you would have to do:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AWSAmplifyWrapper } from './aws-amplify-wrapper';
import { IUser } from '../../models/userModel';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AwsAmplifyAuthService {
  private authenticationSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.authenticationSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  }

  // SignUp
  public signUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return AWSAmplifyWrapper.getAuth().signUp({
      username: user.name,
      password: user.password,
      attributes: {
        email: user.email,
        name:user.name
      }
    });
   }

  // Confirm Code
  public confirmSignUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return AWSAmplifyWrapper.getAuth().confirmSignUp(user.name, user.code);
  }

  // SignIn
  public signIn(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    return AwsAmplify.getAuth().signIn(user.name, user.password)
      .then((r) => {
        console.log('signIn response', r);
        this.authenticationSubject.next(true);
        if (user) {
          if (r.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/forgotpass');
          } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

And in your unit test:

```
 import { AWSAplifyWrapper } from './aws-amplify-wrapper';
 beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
    })
      .compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.inject(AwsAmplifyAuthService);
  });


  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('#signIn should return expected data', async () => {
    spyOn(AWSAmplifyWrapper, 'getAuth').and.returnValue({
       signIn: () => Promise.resolve({/* mock how you wish here */});
       // likewise you can mock signUp and confirmSignUp the same
    });
    const data = await service.signIn(expectedData);
    // your assertions on data
    // I would assert whether router.navigateByUrl was called or not
    expect(data).toEqual(expectedData);
  });
```

See https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414 and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935131/7365461 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Always inject all dependencies instead of accessing them directly from your code. With this approach, you can always mock them where it's needed.

For example, you can create a root token to inject `Auth`:

```js
export const AWS_AMPLIFY_AUTH = new InjectionToken('AWS_AMPLIFY_AUTH', {
  factory: () => Auth,
  providedIn: 'root',
});
```

then you can inject it in your service like `@Inject(AWS_AMPLIFY_AUTH) private auth: typeof Auth`, and use `this.auth` to call methods:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
class AwsAmplifyAuthService {
  private authenticationSubject: BehaviorSubject<any>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,

    // INJECTION
    @Inject(AWS_AMPLIFY_AUTH) private auth: typeof Auth,
  ) {
    this.authenticationSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  }

  public async signUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    // CHANGE TO this.auth
    return this.auth.signUp({
      username: user.name,
      password: user.password,
      attributes: {
        email: user.email,
        name: user.name,
      },
    });
  }

  public confirmSignUp(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    // CHANGE TO this.auth
    return this.auth.confirmSignUp(user.name, user.code);
  }

  public async signIn(user: IUser): Promise<any> {
    // CHANGE TO this.auth
    const r = await this.auth.signIn(user.name, user.password);

    console.log('signIn response', r);
    this.authenticationSubject.next(true);
    if (user) {
      if (r.challengeName === 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED') {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/forgotpass');
      } else {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your test you need to provide both of them: the service and a mock token:

```js
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        AwsAmplifyAuthService, // <- add it
        {
          provide: AWS_AMPLIFY_AUTH, // <- add a mock
          useValue: {
            signIn: () => Promise.resolve({
              challengeName: 'NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED',
            }),
            currentUserInfo: () => Promise.resolve('hello'),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    service = TestBed.inject(AwsAmplifyAuthService);
  });
```

profit, now you can manipulate `Auth` in your tests.