# Jasmine 4 ANgular 13 CryptoBrowserify publicEncrypt Error spyOn> : publicEncrypt is not declared writable or has no setter

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular13

publicEncrypt is not declared writable or has no setter

```
 beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
        spyOn(CryptoBrowserify, 'publicEncrypt').and.returnValue(Buffer.from('ENCRYPT', 'utf8'));
        
      }));

Error: <spyOn> : publicEncrypt is not declared writable or has no setter
    Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
    Error: <spyOn> : publicEncrypt is not declared writable or has no setter
    Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

Comment: It seems like you want to `spyOn` an imported library function. It is not possible to do that anymore with the changes/updates to TypeScript. I have found this to be the best method in spying on imported libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60259259/error-supportsscrollbehavior-is-not-declared-configurable/62935131#62935131. Read the Github thread as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AliF50  Thank you, working fine with Wrapper class,   did you get a chance to write test case for wrapper class? we need to cover 100%,
export class CryptoBrowserifyWrapper {
  public static publicEncrypt(...args) {
    return publicEncryptLocal(...args);
  }
}

Comment: I am not sure how to test the wrapper class, I personally did not test it. Show your boss this tweet: https://twitter.com/BenLesh/status/912487170371284994 ;).

Answer (score -1):

So this is telling you that the property is not `writable`.

You can work around this by overriding the property [descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) for the duration of your test

Note that you can only do this if the property is `configurable`.

I have found that in Angular if you do the below prop descriptors come as **non**-configurable so you will not be able to apply the solution

```js
// this will cause prop descriptors to come as non-configurable
import from 'zone.js'
```

So in your `test.ts` do this instead

```js
// this will cause prop descriptors to come as configurable
import from 'zone.js/dist/zone'
import from 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing'
```

```js
import * as someNsObj from 'external/lib';

// get the current descriptor
const originalDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(someNsObj, 'targetFunction');

// replace with a writable prop
beforeAll(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(someNsObj, 'targetFunction', {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true, // this is what makes the difference
    value: () => {}, // or whatever makes sense
  });
});

// restore the original descriptor
afterAll(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(someNsObj, 'targetFunction', originalDesc);
});
```