# How can an angular global variable be tested which is instantiated with new Object?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

```
export class AddRouteComponent implements OnInit {
workforce: Workforce;

save() {
  workforce = new Workforce();
  workforce.name = form.controls.value("name");
}
}
```

This is obviously a simplified version of what I'm trying to test.  I'd like to write a jasmine test that has workforce equal a const of the object so I can properly test all properties of that object.  Normally I'd have component.workforce = testWorkforce, but the new Workforce doesn't allow this to work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Mock the Workforce.

Comment: @Iank81 the code you share does not return anything or sets any global variable so you can't test anything, if you want to fulfill coverage just check if `value` method is called inside the function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't mock `new Workforce()`. The best way I have found to do it is using the following response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935131/7365461.

For you, it could be:

1.) Create a wrapper class.

```
export class WorkforceWrapper() {
  static createWorkforce() {
     return new Workforce();
  }
}
```

2.) Use wrapper class in component or class.

```
save() {
  workforce = WorkforceWrapper.createWorkforce();
  // the rest
}
```

3.) Modify your tests:

```
spyOn(WorkforceWrapper, 'createWorkforce').and.returnValue({/* return whatever you wish here */ });
```