# how to spyOn on a function imported from a helper file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a helper file, which contains only one function, which uses transloco translate method.

**translate.utils.ts**

```
  import { translate } from "@ngneat/transloco";
  import { SelectItem } from "primeng/api";

  export function someFunction(param: any[]): any[] {
    return param.map((obj:any) => {
      const newLabel= translate(obj.label as any);
      obj.label = newLabel;
      return obj;
    }) as any;
  }
```

I have imported this function in my angular component

Like this

```
import { someFunction } from '../utils/translate.utils';
..
//somewher in the component used as 

data = someFunction(SOME_OPTIONS)
```

while running the test, i'm getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'translate')

how to mock `someFunction`? or fix this translate?

Test were coded in jasmine

Tried mocking like

1. spyOn(window, "translate").and.callFake((label: string) => `Translated ${label}`);
2. import * as translate from '../utils/translate.utils'
   spyOn(translate, "translate").and.callFake((label: string) => `Translated ${label}`);

nothing works, any leads would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, as TypeScript evolved, it's not possible to spy on imported function the way you have tried in Jasmine. Here is a long Github issue on the topic (https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/1414) and here is the best solution I have found for this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935131/7365461).