# Spec file calling real service despite having a mock spy implementation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, capacitor

I am new to testing. Can't seem to get my spec file to call the mocked version of my service dependency during a test. Instead, it calls the original, which doesnt work because it's an API that only runs on a native device.

Function in service being tested:

```
async startScan(): Promise<string | boolean> {

    BarcodeScanner.hideBackground(); // make background of WebView transparent

    try {
      const result = await BarcodeScanner.startScan(); 
      if (result.hasContent) {
        console.log(result.content); 
        return result.content;
      }
      return false;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("could not activate scanner. Are you on a mobile device?", error);
      return false; 
    }
  };
```

My mock BarcodeScanner service:

```
export const BarcodeScanner = {
    startScan: (options?: ScanOptions): Promise<ScanResult> => Promise.resolve({
        hasContent: true,
        content: 'mockContent',
        format: 'mockFormat'
    }),
}
```

My spec file:

```
import { ScannerService } from './scanner.service';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '../__mocks__/@capacitor/barcode-scanner';


describe('ScannerService', () => {
  let scannerService: ScannerService
  let barcodeScannerSpy: any
  let capacitorCoreSpy: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    barcodeScannerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('BarcodeScanner', ['hideBackground',
      'showBackground',
      'stopScan',
      'checkPermissions',
      'openAppSettings',
      'checkPermission']);

    capacitorCoreSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Capacitor', ['isNativePlatform']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ScannerService,
        { provide: BarcodeScanner, useValue: barcodeScannerSpy },
        { provide: Capacitor, useValue: capacitorCoreSpy }

      ]
    });

    scannerService = TestBed.inject(ScannerService) as jasmine.SpyObj<ScannerService>;
    capacitorCoreSpy.isNativePlatform.and.returnValue(true);
  });

  it('should start scan', fakeAsync(() => {
    let result: any;

    scannerService.startScan().then(res => {
      console.log("res", res);
      result = res
    });

    expect(result).toEqual('mockContent');
  }));
});
```

Result:

```
ScannerService > should start scan
Expected undefined to equal 'mockContent'.
```

This returns false, because it hits the catch error case, due to calling the original, which does not work in the web browser.

How do I make this call the fake spy? Thanks, help appreciated.

Comment: Service mocks need to be resolved using dependency injection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `BarCodeScanner` an injected service? Meaning inside of the `ScannerService`, is it like this:

```
constructor(private BarCodeScanner: BarCodeScanner) {}
```

or

```
private BarCodeScanner = inject(BarCodeScanner);
```

I ask because `BarCodeScanner` is in `PascalCase` and usually injected services are in `camelCase`.

If it's an injected service, what you have is fine and maybe you need to return a value:

```
it('should start scan', fakeAsync(() => {
    // make the spy of startScan return a value
    barcodeScannerSpy.startScan.and.resolveTo({
        hasContent: true,
        content: 'mockContent',
        format: 'mockFormat'
    });
    let result: any;

    scannerService.startScan().then(res => {
      console.log("res", res);
      result = res
    });

    // You most likely will need a tick here to make sure
    // the promise above (.then) completed before asserting result
    tick();

    expect(result).toEqual('mockContent');
  }));
```

If `BarCodeScanner` is not an injected service (it is just an import), then unfortunately this is a limitation of `TypeScript` and `Jasmine` and you will have to mock it a different way.

You are going to have to create a Wrapper class for BarCodeScanner.

```
export class BarcodeScannerWrapper {
  startScan() {
    return BarcodeScanner.startScan();
  }

  hideBackground() {
    return BarcodeScanner.hideBackground();
  }
  // wrapper methods continue
}
```

In your service, you will have to do:

```
import { BarcodeScannerWrapper } from './bar-code-scanner-wrapper'; // the above file

// every time you have to use it, use the wrapper.


BarcodeScannerWrapper.hideBackground();

...

BarCodeScannerWrapper.startScan();
```

Then in your test, since it's not a dependency injection anymore, you will have to do the following:

```
// Remove this line since we are not mocking a dependency injection
// { provide: Capacitor, useValue: capacitorCoreSpy }
```

```
it('should start scan', fakeAsync(() => {
    let result: any;
    // Spy on the wrapper
    spyOn(BarcodeScannerWrapper, 'hideBackground');
    spyOn(BarcodeScannerWrapper, 'startScan').and.resolveTo({
        hasContent: true,
        content: 'mockContent',
        format: 'mockFormat'
    });

    scannerService.startScan().then(res => {
      console.log("res", res);
      result = res
    });

    tick();

    expect(result).toEqual('mockContent');
  }));
```

The above has been taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62935131/7365461

If none of the above works, if you can output the `error`, maybe that can be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

AliF50's answer is correct.

I should add that an eloquent way of using this wrapper in a test environment and not in a dev/prod environment without adding conditional statements to the code is to add paths to your tsconfig.spec.ts file. I implemented your solution with this:

```
    "paths": {
      ...,
      ...,
      "@capacitor/*": ["__mocks__/@capacitor/*"],
      ...,
      ...,

    },
```

This will replace every instance of that property name with the property value whenever your code is run from a spec file.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but a complement. SO's format s Q&A